# Regular expression that allows square-brackets

Tags: regex, vb.net, .net-4.0

This works perfect..

```vb
 result2 = Regex.Replace(result2, "[^A-Za-z0-9/.,>#:\s]", "", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

But I need to allow square brackets (`[` and `]`).
Does this look correct to allow Brackets without changing what is allowed and not allowed from the above?

```
result2 = Regex.Replace(result2, "[^A-Za-z0-9\[\]/.,>#:\s]", "", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

Reason I need a second opinion is that I think if this is correct something else is blocking it that is out of my control.

Comment: Not sure about your language, but generally `[][abc]` is a character class comprising the characters `][abc`. In other words, putting the close bracket first disambiguates it.

Comment: Currently characters A-Z a-z 0-9 / . , > # : and single spaces are allowed, everything else is replace with "". I am trying to add the ability to allow [ and ]. I was under the impression that it had to be enclosed in Brackets and have seen many examples with the Brackets on the outside like I have above.

Comment: Your second regular expression ought to work.  If it is not, then you should consider escaping your backslashes: `"[^A-Za-z0-9\\[\\]/.,>#:\s]"`.  I'm no .net expert, but it's a common problem.

Comment: You can also shorten your regex using the \w shorthand instead of A-Za-z0-9, that is: `[^\w\\[\\]/.,>#:\s]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant say any one person did or did not answer the question or try to help, I would split the solution among everyone if I could because it made me think. The key was to separate the  brackets by using a single \ . Thanks everyone for your help.

```
  result = Regex.Replace(result, "[^A-Za-z0-9/\[\].,>#\s]", "", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

Answer (score 0):

The gimmick @tripleee mentioned does indeed work in .NET.  Just make sure `]` is the first character (or in this case, first after the `^`.

```
result2 = Regex.Replace(result2, "[^][A-Za-z0-9/.,>#:\s]", "");
```

But be careful about porting the regex to other flavors.  Some will treat it as a syntax error, and some will treat it as two atoms: `[^]` and `[A-Za-z0-9/.,>#:\s]`, the first of which matches literally anything but nothing--i.e., any character including newlines.

On a side note, why are you using the `RegexOptions.Compiled` option?  That's something you should use only when you *know* you need it.  The increased performance will almost never be significant, and it comes with a pretty high price tag, as explained [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f.aspx

Comment: Sounded like a good idea at the time... I used it before to only allow upper and lower case a-z and 0-9 so it seemed logical to use it here. I am not concerned about performance so I could use anything that worked.